# View as Webpage custom setup for retrieval not working as expected

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We recently added view as webpage URLs to our send logging data extension in order to show that url in another email.

Article for reference: https://code.exacttarget.com/question/rebuild-view-web-page-url (suggested solution implemented)
This is set in the template our email is using

```
Set @VAWP = TreatAsContent(view_email_url)
```

After exporting the send log I do see the data being populated.

I also can click on the link in the email that is pulling the send log value, it's just throwing a system error.

Here are some code snippets from the email pulling the link from the send log:

AMPscript:

```
Set @VAWP = LookupOrderedRows("WarmCallReport_VAWP",1,"JobID Desc","consultantNumber", consultantNumber)

     if ROWCOUNT(@VAWP) > 0 then
       SET @vawplink = FIELD(ROW(@VAWP, 1), "VAWP")
     endif
```

HTML:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@vawplink)=%%">Click here</a>
```

When the url is clicked in the email we get directed to this page: http://view.mail.thepamperedchef.com/?j=fec91372776c067c&m=fe9015707361037571&ls=fe2413737c67027e771076&l=fed415727565047a&s=fe5a167772620578751d&jb=ffce15&ju=&utm_medium=Email&utm_source=ExactTarget&utm_campaign=

With text: "The system is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for any inconvenience. Please try again later.”

This solution worked just a week ago, not sure what would be causing this issue now.

I did notice that the ju parameter value is missing from the stored value in the send log, when I send the original email (the one that is storing the view email link to the send log) to a recipient and click the view email link that ju parameter is populated.

Comment: Several Questions:

1. Is this the same URL as a week ago?  

2. Who hosts this URL?  ET or PamperedChef or someone else?

3. Do you have the URL in an older email?  Does it still work?

Comment: it is not the same URL as a week ago, but the same implementation and variable (view_email_url is unique for each recipient, each send I think). ET hosts the view as webpage url. I do have the URL in an older email and it no longer works.

Answer (score 3):

This error is caused when the online view cannot access the data in the Sendable Data Extension you originally sent to. Usually because the Data Extension has been cleared, overwritten or deleted. When you click the view_email_url, the hosted page will try to render the email on the fly based on the data extension it was sent to. If the data is gone, this error is shown.

The solution is to use the **_SendContext** variable to pull the fields from the Sendlog instead of the Sendable DE.

In the following code example. I use _SendContext to lookup the values out of the Sendlog based on the combination of **JobID**, **SubscriberID** and **BatchID**. The combination of these 3 fields acts as the primary key in any ET Sendlog and will never be duplicated (unless you insert some data yourself). Technically they are not marked as the primary keys, but you can be confident the combination will be unique and you will always pull back the correct record.

```
%%[

/* If the message is being viewed as a webpage, on social forward, or as forward to a friend */
if _MessageContext == "VAWP" or _MessageContext == "Social" or _MessageContext == "FTAF" then

    /* Set the firstname from the Sendlog */
    set @FirstName = LookUp("Sendlog","FirstName","SubID",SubscriberID,"JobID",JobID,"BatchID",_JobSubscriberBatchID)

else

    /* Set the firstname variable from the DE */
    set @FirstName = FirstName

endif

]%%
```

Here is the article on ET help docs about SendContext, but it does not show to use BatchID which I feel is incomplete.
http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_use_ampscript_to_contextually_display_send_time_content/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am retrieving this URL from the sendlog, what I don't understand is the original view as webpage link in the emails work, just not the ones pulled from the send log, they are missing the ju parameter value at the end. Since I'm setting the variable for the sendlog at time of send I was expecting the value stored in the sendlog to match the value used in the email header's 'click here' link.

Comment: I do not retrieve it directly from the send log in the email as the send log can grow (even with data retention) so to save send time processing I have a query setup to pull the send log data out that is relevant to my use:
`SELECT consultantNumber, VAWP, JobID
FROM SendLog_Last31Days
WHERE VAWP != '' 
AND isConsultant = 'true'
AND exists(SELECT JobID FROM WarmCallReport_eNewsJobs WHERE SendLog_Last31Days.JobID = JobID)`

Comment: Try removing TreatAsContent(), and just use `Set @VAWP = view_email_url`. I am doing this succesfully without using that function.    Also verify that your Sendable DE has not been overwritten or cleared.

Comment: Also, do you use Data Retention on the Sendable DE?

Comment: I do not have data retention on the sendable DE, however it does get overwritten nightly with a filter activity, I do know the subscriber data in question is still there so the lookups should all be functioning correctly. Also the original link in the email header still works, I'd think both would stop working if the issue was linked to the sendable DE being overwritten. And I will try removing the TreatAsContent()

Comment: My processes use Queries or Imports to overwrite Data Extensions and not Filter Activities, so there might be something different there. However, everything I know about ET right now suggests that because you are overwriting the DE's nightly, this is what would cause the VAWP link to break. If you are 100% sure that the old emails VAWP URL still works even after the DE is overwritten by the Filter, then I am at a bit of a loss and would have to recreate a similar process using Filters to test on my account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14931/discussion-between-jsakas-and-carrie-bennett).