# %%view_email_url%% - renders template dynamically instead of showing email version

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

My email tempalte is populated by the means of using a dynamic data coming from JSON api.

I have this %%view_email_url%% to view the email in the browser -> so what I want is to display email as it was sent, but instead it appears like all the ssjs code get's re-executed and template get's re-populated with fresh data from api...

How can I just display email html as it was sent out?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a SendLog based VAWP implementation. When email gets send out, whatever data is used for personalisation gets stored in a SendLog Data Extension. This ensures you store a snapshot of how data looked when email was sent out, and not how it looks when VAWP link is clicked. There is a good article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5), on what SendLog is and how to enable it.

You can get some guidance on a custom VAWP setup in this thread: [View as Webpage custom setup for retrieval not working as expected](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38774/view-as-webpage-custom-setup-for-retrieval-not-working-as-expected)