# View as a web page: keep the content of the sent email day after day

Tags: marketing-cloud

In my company we're sending a daily newsletter with a content updated every day.
This content is from a XML file wich is actually updated a lot of time during the day, so the newsletter is sent with the "actual" version of the XML.

If the user clicks on the "view as a web page" link in the newsletter today from the newsletter received yesterday, he will see the email with data for today, instead of the yesterday. This is a problem as the newsletter has not yet been sent for today.

I searched quite a lot here and on Google and found that the Send Log might be the solution. However, I'm missing something, I don't see how it can help me.
I am able to store the VAWP link into a Data Extension, for each Contact who received the newsletter but, what should I do with this link ?
The link for the newsletter is always the same (in the received email or in my Send Log Data Extension) so I don't get the point to have it in this Data Extension.

I especially saw this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248015/view-email-url-renders-template-dynamically-instead-of-showing-email-versi) which seems to be the same as mine. 
However the links shown in the answer are not enough for me to answer my questions.

Do you have an idea to help me ?

Thank you !

Divad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/sendTimeContent.htm

The idea is not to store the VAWP link in the send log, but to store all dynamic variables with their value at send time.

Then, if the "context" of accessing the email is VAWP, the lookup is done into the send log instead of the original sendout data extension in which the data might have changed or disappeared in the meantime.

Comment: Hi Jonas, 
Thanks a lot for your super-fast answer.

I understand better as you said I should store dynamic content into my Send Log DE, then use this code sample to help me to show the good data.
I understand that this code, in my case, will say:
" If the email is seen from the VAWP, then show the value stored in the variable @SendLogData "

Comment: I then have another question:
Should we store all the HTML generated with the dynamic contents in 1 variable in the Send Log DE ? Are we then limitated to 4000 characters ? 
Our newsletter have hundreds of dynamic values. We actually display offers with a FOR statment. The HTML generated is very big.